# Best way to transform data values in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What is the best way to replace specific values using a Azure Data factory?
The case, for example: Need to lead to a single value brand "ssang yong" and model "ceed" for brand "kia". 
Data source:

```
{
    id: 1
    brand: "ssang yong",
    model: "rexton"
},
{
    id: 2
    brand: "ssang_yong",
    model: "rexton"
},
{
    id: 3
    brand: "ssangyong",
    model: "rexton"
},
{
    id: 4
    brand: "kia",
    model: "ceed"
},
{
    id: 5
    brand: "kia",
    model: "c'eed"
}
```

**Pattern:**

```
 { 
        target: "brand",
        common_value: "ssang yong",
        condition: {
            brand: ["ssang-yong", "ssangyong"]
        }
    },
    {
        target: "model",
        common_value: "ceed",
         condition: {
            brand: ["kia"],
            model: ["c'eed"]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please give more information? Data factory is not used to change data, but to move it. Most times you can change something in a query to get what you want, but tell me how are you using ADF, where are you extracting the data from and where are you moving it to?

Comment: Thanks I'm new to Azure. I have several data sources with different accessibility. MongoDb, Mysql, csv files. The data in the sources have a similar structure, but some of the same values have differences (ssang yong, ssangyong, ssang-yong). I need to collect the data as soon as the sources are available, transform to common format and provide them for analysis to power bi accounts.
a) sources -> b) transform data -> c) tables in Azure Table Storage -> d) power bi 
I can't transform data by the bi. There is one pattern that is compatible for transforming data from any source.

Comment: Couldn't you add HDInsight to the pipeline and transform it via a map/reduce job?

Comment: As far as I know this kind of change is possible in the Edit Query in Power Bi using power query, see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260659.aspx

Comment: @MartinEstebanZurita  I do not have access to the Power BI accounts. It is necessary to prepare the data before import into BI.

Answer (score 0):

ADF is mostly used to move data from one place to another and to manage ELT process. 
So my use case in this scenario would be:
1) copy raw data with ADF to ADLS from sources
2) perform transformations with Azure data lake analytics and save output to the new file
3) import file into power bi (if you do not have analysis service to create tabular model)